Capture output of subprocess.run but don't print it
Is there a way to capture the stdout of a subprocess.run() command, without having it printed out in the command prompt?
Using capture_output=True allows to read from the stdout, but also prints to the command window, which I'm trying to avoid...

it does, subprocess.check_output() is what I was looking for. Ty Brian

capture_output should prevent stdout and stderr from going to the terminal. Are you sure it's not writing to /dev/tty?

capture_output=True is basically just a shortcut for stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE. subprocess.check_output() is a shortcut for stdout=PIPE, check=True.
